# jQuery: animate image to go left and right continuously

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to get my image to move continuiously back and forth left to right but it keeps going left and never returns right.  I'm following a code that I found, I can't seem to find what I'm doing wrong.

http://jsfiddle.net/7kmmxeeg/1/

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
 function firstleft() {
  $(".block.first").animate({"left": "-=100px" }, 1500, "swing", firstright);
 }
 function firstright() {
  $(".block.first").animate({"right": "+=100px" }, 1500, "swing", firstleft);
 }
 firstleft();
});
```

```css
div.container {
 position:relative; 
 background-color:rgba(149, 187, 206, 0.36);
 height:700px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

div.block {
 height:200px;
 width:200px;
 background-color:blue;
 overflow:hidden;
}

div.block.first {
 position:absolute;
 left:100px;
 top:300px;
 overflow:hidden;
}

div.block.second {
 position:absolute;
 top:10px;
 left:500px;
 background-color:green;
 overflow:hidden;
}

div.block.third {
 position:relative;
 top:350px;
 left:500px;
 background-color:red;
}

div.block.first img {
 background-size:cover;
 width:400px;
 margin-left:-100px;
}

div.block.second img {
 background-size:cover;
 width:400px;
 margin-left:-100px;
}

div.block.third img {
 background-size:cover;
 width:400px;
 margin-left:-100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="container">
 <div class="block first">
  <img src="img/first.jpg"> 
 </div>
 
 <div class="block second">
  <img src="img/second.jpg">
 </div>
 
 <div class="block third">
  <img src="img/third.jpg">
 </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

ANSWER: Change `right` to `left` in the `firstright()` function.

```
function firstleft() {
    $(".block.first").animate({"left": "-=100px" }, 1500, "swing", firstright);
}
function firstright() {
    $(".block.first").animate({"left": "+=100px" }, 1500, "swing", firstleft);
}
```

## [Updated Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/7kmmxeeg/3/)